# SQLiteDataReader type affinity bug?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

SQLite can store value of any type in column of any other type. When I try to read such different-type value from .net app with SQLiteDataReader it performs conversion to column-defined type even if I try to read it as an object. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SqliteTypeAffinityTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:"))
            {
                // advise from @Shawn to use NoVerifyTypeAffinity does not help, neither separate nor combined with default

                // connection.Flags = SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoVerifyTypeAffinity;
                // connection.Flags = connection.Flags | SQLiteConnectionFlags.NoVerifyTypeAffinity;

                connection.Open();

                using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE t(b BLOB)";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t(b) VALUES (x'FF')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t(b) VALUES ('FF')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT b, typeof(b) AS type FROM t";
                    using (var reader = (SQLiteDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        reader.Read();

                        object t1 = reader.GetValue(0);
                        string sqliteType1 = reader.GetString(1);

                        reader.Read();

                        object t2 = reader.GetValue(0);
                        string sqliteType2 = reader.GetString(1);

                        Type netType1 = t1.GetType();
                        Type netType2 = t2.GetType();

                        Console.WriteLine("sqlite type #1: {0}, .net type #1: {1}", sqliteType1, netType1);
                        Console.WriteLine("sqlite type #2: {0}, .net type #2: {1}", sqliteType2, netType2);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Console output will be:

```
sqlite type #1: blob, .net type #1: System.Byte[]
sqlite type #2: text, .net type #2: System.Byte[]
```

Note that .net type #2 is System.Byte[] (SQLite type is text!), however I would expect that it would be a System.String.

Is there any way to read this value as string? I understand that I can also request value type as in my example and perform some conversion after reading, but I'd like to avoid it.

EDIT #1 to be more correct in my question, after reply of @MikeT. I am not searching for the way to read column as string. I need to read each value with its own type. So in my example t1 must remain as byte[], but t2 must be a string. I've updated my example to make it more explicit (previously there was 1 row with two BLOB columns).

EDIT #2 including full test text with 'using' to make more obvious used library and more easy to reproduce

Comment: "SQLite can store value of any type in column of any other type." Wow, that sounds very weird and counterintuitive. Does it aim to keep information about what type of information was actually stored? Do you have any links about that? (It sounds like a *really, really* bad idea to be honest, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Actually I see there's some information about that here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's the driver that's performing the conversion - I'd hope that there'd be some way of disabling that in the connection string, but [I can't see anything](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection~ConnectionString.html)

Comment: @JonSkeet I am really excited to get 3 comment from you! Your last link is to DevArt library, not sure but I think they may have some specific connection string options, not the same as in System.Data.SQLite library. I've made decompile of GetValue method (and then found it here - http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/400bce215e000cea) and it looks like there is something that can be driven by SQLiteConnectionFlags. I've tried some but no luck for now. But your attention to this gives me the power and I think I'll try to debug it more!

Comment: Ah - it wasn't clear which you were using, given the lack of using directives etc. That's where a [mcve] really helps. Given that there are multiple SQLite drivers available, I'd strongly recommend making it clear in your question which one you're using.

Comment: Looking at the source, it appears that yes, GetValue() tries to be clever and maps the actual stored value to the column affinity type by default. The `NoVerifyTypeAffinity` connection flag *might* prevent this.

Comment: @JonSkeet In defense of the accused, question was tagged with 'system.data.sqlite', however I agree this may be not opvious from text - updated question, thanks for making it better!

Comment: @Shawn - thanks for suggestion, but it does not helps :(. I've added both tries as comments in my sample.

Answer (score 1):

Blob's are often not well represented by third party SQLite tools. However, I believe that using the `hex(the_value)` will make them reasonably(sic) readable.

e.g. Consider the table (Text and Blob in the same column, especially for Jon :) ) :-

[image]

using (wrongly due to the dates) :-

```
SELECT hex(data) FROM convdt;
```

Yields :-

[image]

P.S. Inserted using x'FF00FE01FD02' (into a column with type affinity as TEXT)
- You can use the **quote** function to return X'FF00FE01FD02'

Or to hanlde the different columns types you could use :-

```
SELECT typeof(data), CASE WHEN typeof(data) = 'blob' THEN hex(data) ELSE data END AS data FROM convdt;
```

and get :-

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sorry I cannot accept it. That's not what I am searching for. Updating query will cast all values from all rows to some specified type. But I need to know value with its type for each row.